# Unexpected parameter "help","topics" in bash function

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a simple backup program in bash as follow :

```sh
export tmfmt=%Y.%m.%d:%H:%M:%S #+%Z
function bk()
{
    local tmstp=`date +$tmfmt`
    set "$@"
    while (("$#"))
    do
        cp "$1" ".$1.backup.$tmstp.${1##*.}"
        ln -sfT ".$1.backup.$tmstp.${1##*.}" ".$1.backup.${1##*.}"
        shift
    done
}
```

It will be inserted into my `~/.bashrc`.

---

I tried it in a tmp dir :

```sh
~ $ cd ~/tmp; touch t.t; ls -A
t.t
~/tmp $
```

and then :

```sh
~/tmp $ bk t.t ;ls -A
.help.backup.help  .topics.backup.topics  t.t  .t.t.backup.2021.12.03:15:45:27.t  .t.t.backup.t
~/tmp $
```

Where `.help.backup.help` `.topics.backup.topics` come from?

Besides, why they will not be created if I redo these but ran `bk *` instead?

Thanks.

---

#### EDIT :

I found that it will happened if I type `b` `k`   `t` `.` `t` `<TAB>`.

The `_init_completion` will run a block as follow :

```sh
+ [[ -n '' ]]
+ return 0
++ bk help topics
++ awk '/^  bk/ { print $2 }'
++ xargs printf '%s '
```

The unexpected files would be created after completion. What is the completion script doing here, and how to avoid this?

Comment: What is `set "$@"` doing there? What do you mean, what do you want `set` to do? `Where .help.backup.help .topics.backup.topics come from?` Add `set -x` and find out, if they come from that function. Anyway, can't reproduce [replit.com link](https://replit.com/@kamilcukrowski/JuvenileMindlessGames#main.sh).

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks for advice, I done just now. In fact after  ```set -x```(but still in the same shell process),  the unexpected files are no longer appear. Although before ```set -x``` I had tried many times (like add ```echo "$@"``` at the beginning of function and retry, it showed arguments are just ```t.t```) and they were still appeared before...

Comment: @KamilCuk About ```set "$@"```, I was not sure that if I send argument like ```"a b.txt"``` it could be treated as a single argument when I use ```$1```. So I added it.

Comment: Tangentially, your function would more idiomatically be reduced to `local tmstp=$(date +"$tmfmt"); local f; for f; do cp "$1" ".$1.backup.$tmstp.${1##*.}"; ln -sfT ".$1.backup.$tmstp.${1##*.}" ".$1.backup.${1##*.}"; done`